# Laravel 5.4 Queue Driver says email notification is processed, but email is not sent

Tags: laravel, queue

I am trying to implement email notification when an event is fired. When an event is fired, the listener will fire a notification which is an email.

Email is sent when I have not implemented Queue. Email is not sent if I have implemented Queue approach.

When I run the queue worker, it gives me the below outpt. But email is not sent.

```
[2019-02-24 11:10:25] Processing: App\Notifications\CustomRequestListener
[2019-02-24 11:10:25] Processed:  App\Notifications\CustomRequestListener
```

I have configured listeners, events, notifications as below.

**Listener**

```
 class CustomRequestListener 
 {   
    public function handle(CustomRequestCreated $event)   
    {
      $user->notify(new CustomRequestEmail());   
    } 
 }
```

**Notification Class**

```
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class CustomRequestEmail extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject('Test Mail')
            ->view('layout.testmail.template');
    }
}
```

**queue.php**

```
'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'database'),
```

'connections' => [

```
    'sync' => [
        'driver' => 'sync',
    ],

    'database' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'jobs',
        'queue' => 'default',
        'retry_after' => 90,
    ],
```

**.env**

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=database
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue in the above code is that, shouldQueue is implemented on the notification class where as it really needs to be implemented on the listener.

code given below solved the issue.

**Remove ShouldQueue from notification**

```
class CustomRequestEmail extends Notification
{
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
          ->subject('Test Mail')
          ->view('layout.testmail.template');
    }
}
```

**Add shouldQueue to the listener**

```
class CustomRequestListener implements ShouldQueue
 {   
    public function handle(CustomRequestCreated $event)   
    {
      $user->notify(new CustomRequestEmail());   
    } 
 }
```